# how to request twitter home timeline showing top Tweets first?

Tags: http, twitter, social-networking

When a user is logged in on the Twitter's home page, there are two options for visualisation:

1. "Home shows you top Tweets first"
2. "Latest Tweets show up as they happen"

I've checked the Twitter API 1.1 (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline), but the only option is to request the latest tweets.
Is there any way to request top tweets first?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not available in the API. The v1.1 home timeline endpoint only provides most recent Tweets; the v2 home timeline endpoint functionality is not yet fully developed.